Make a robot do a sequence of actions NAV2
I'm working with ROS2 Humble and using the Nav2 stack. I'm trying to create a custom behavior tree but I'm having trouble finding a complete example to guide me through the process. Here's what I'm aiming to achieve:
I want to trigger the behavior tree when a "start_journey" message is received on the "journey" topic.
The behavior tree should execute the following sequence:
1 - Detect object (using a custom action node plugin I've created)

2 - Spin (using a plugin from Nav2)

3 - Detect object (using a custom action node plugin I've created)

4 - Spin (using a plugin from Nav2)

My question is: Do developers typically use bt_navigator with a custom XML file while focusing on writing custom action node plugins? If so, how do they modify the start condition to initiate the behavior tree in response to a specific message, instead of the default goal position publication?
To summarize, my main inquiry is how to write, configure, and launch a custom behavior tree with Nav2, allowing a robot to perform a sequence of actions using a mix of custom and pre-existing Nav2 plugins.
As a learning exercise, I attempted to create my own BT action node plugin called "DetectObject," which is essentially a copy of the "Wait" plugin, but I encountered the following error:
[bt_navigator-16] [INFO] [1725360311.211556591] [bt_navigator]: Activating
[bt_navigator-16] [ERROR] [1725360312.424422568] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: "DetectObject" action server not available after waiting for 1.00s
[bt_navigator-16] [ERROR] [1725360312.461249410] [bt_navigator]: Exception when loading BT: Action server DetectObject not available
[bt_navigator-16] [ERROR] [1725360312.461552836] [bt_navigator]: Error loading XML file: /home/vivi/ros2_ws/src/myrobot_bringup/config/behavior_tree/myrobot_bt_test.xml
[lifecycle_manager-19] [ERROR] [1725360312.465501585] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to change state for node: bt_navigator
[lifecycle_manager-19] [ERROR] [1725360312.465723957] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to bring up all requested nodes. Aborting bringup.


Could you please help me fix this? Thank you.
Here is my code:
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include "myrobot_behavior_tree/action/detect_object_action.hpp"

namespace myrobot_behavior_tree
{

DetectObjectAction::DetectObjectAction(
  const std::string & xml_tag_name,
  const std::string & action_name,
  const BT::NodeConfiguration & conf)
: BtActionNode<myrobot_msgs::action::DetectObject>(xml_tag_name, action_name, conf)
{
  int duration;
  getInput("wait_duration", duration);
  if (duration <= 0) {
    RCLCPP_WARN(
      node_->get_logger(), "Wait duration is negative or zero "
      "(%i). Setting to positive.", duration);
    duration *= -1;
  }

  goal_.time.sec = duration;
}

void DetectObjectAction::on_tick()
{
  increment_recovery_count();
}

}  // namespace myrobot_behavior_tree

#include "behaviortree_cpp_v3/bt_factory.h"
BT_REGISTER_NODES(factory)
{
  BT::NodeBuilder builder =
    [](const std::string & name, const BT::NodeConfiguration & config)
    {
      return std::make_unique<myrobot_behavior_tree::DetectObjectAction>(name, "detect_object", config);
    };

  factory.registerBuilder<myrobot_behavior_tree::DetectObjectAction>("DetectObject", builder);
}

Hpp file:
#ifndef MYROBOT_BEHAVIOR_TREE__PLUGINS__ACTION__DETECT_OBJECT_ACTION_HPP_
#define MYROBOT_BEHAVIOR_TREE__PLUGINS__ACTION__DETECT_OBJECT_ACTION_HPP_

#include <string>

#include "nav2_behavior_tree/bt_action_node.hpp"

#include "myrobot_msgs/action/detect_object.hpp"

namespace myrobot_behavior_tree
{
using namespace nav2_behavior_tree;  // NOLINT
/**
 * @brief A nav2_behavior_tree::BtActionNode class that wraps nav2_msgs::action::Wait
 */
class DetectObjectAction : public BtActionNode<myrobot_msgs::action::DetectObject>
{
public:
  /**
   * @brief A constructor for nav2_behavior_tree::WaitAction
   * @param xml_tag_name Name for the XML tag for this node
   * @param action_name Action name this node creates a client for
   * @param conf BT node configuration
   */
  DetectObjectAction(
    const std::string & xml_tag_name,
    const std::string & action_name,
    const BT::NodeConfiguration & conf);

  /**
   * @brief Function to perform some user-defined operation on tick
   */
  void on_tick() override;

  /**
   * @brief Creates list of BT ports
   * @return BT::PortsList Containing basic ports along with node-specific ports
   */
  static BT::PortsList providedPorts()
  {
    return providedBasicPorts(
      {
        BT::InputPort<int>("wait_duration", 1, "Wait time")
      });
  }
};

}  // namespace myrobot_behavior_tree

#endif  // MYROBOT_BEHAVIOR_TREE__PLUGINS__ACTION__DETECT_OBJECT_ACTION_HPP_

The nav2 params config (I am just copying the bt_navigator params):
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odometry/filtered
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    wait_for_service_timeout: 1000
    default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml: "/home/vivi/ros2_ws/src/myrobot_bringup/config/behavior_tree/myrobot_bt_test.xml"
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node
      - myrobot_detect_object_action_bt_node

The behavior tree:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root BTCPP_format="4" main_tree_to_execute="myrobot_bt_test">
  <BehaviorTree ID="myrobot_bt_test">
    <Fallback>
      <Sequence>
        <DetectObject wait_duration="5.0"/>
        <Spin spin_dist="1.57" time_allowance="10.0"/>
        <DetectObject wait_duration="5.0"/>
        <Spin spin_dist="-1.57" time_allowance="10.0"/>
      </Sequence>
    </Fallback>
  </BehaviorTree>

  <!-- Description of Node Models (used by Groot) -->
  <TreeNodesModel>
    <Action ID="Spin">
      <input_port name="spin_dist">Spin distance</input_port>
      <input_port name="time_allowance">Allowed time for spinning</input_port>
    </Action>
    <Action ID="DetectObject">
      <input_port name="wait_duration">Wait time</input_port>
    </Action>
  </TreeNodesModel>

</root>

The launch file is the nav2_bringup launch file "navigation_launch.py"
